# php.ini: which one?

Tags: php

I moved from my old apache to nginx and php 5.3.10. And when I tried to modify php.ini to suit my needs, I found there are 3 of them:

```
$ locate php.ini

/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

Which one should I edit?

Comment: as a follow up on Pekka: look in your `phpinfo()` for _Configuration File (php.ini) Path_

Comment: @Pekka I'm worried that each php.ini will work in a different situation (cli, web, fast cgi).

Comment: You can ask `phpinfo()` in every one of those situations

Comment: @Pekka Thanks, now I did that. So fpm is for web, and cli is for cli. Is it a common/good practice to maintain 2 php.ini? I always used only 1

Comment: @happy: yes, it is, because CLI is a totally different environment from fpm/cgi - many settings are different.

Comment: You can do `$ php -i | grep -P "php.ini"` in a terminal, it will tell you what php.ini is being used and loaded for cli.

Answer (score 80):

Generally speaking, the `cli/php.ini` file is used when the PHP binary is called from the command-line.

You can check that running `php --ini` from the command-line.

`fpm/php.ini` will be used when PHP is run as FPM -- which is the case with an nginx installation.

And you can check that calling `phpinfo()` from a php page served by your webserver.

`cgi/php.ini`, in your situation, will most likely not be used.

Using two distinct `php.ini` files *(one for CLI, and the other one to serve pages from your webserver)* is done quite often, and has one main advantages : it allows you to have different configuration values in each case.

Typically, in the `php.ini` file that's used by the web-server, you'll specify a rather short `max_execution_time` : web pages should be served fast, and if a page needs more than a few dozen seconds *(30 seconds, by default)*, it's probably because of a bug -- and the page's generation should be stopped.

On the other hand, you can have pretty long scripts launched from your crontab (or by hand), which means the `php.ini` file that will be used is the one in `cli/`. For those scripts, you'll specify a much longer `max_execution_time` in `cli/php.ini` than you did in `fpm/php.ini`.

`max_execution_time` is a common example ; you could do the same with several other configuration directives, of course.

Comment: I was of the opinion that the CLI PHP exe totally ignored the max_execution_time, for obvious reasons

Answer (score 5):

Although Pascal's answer was detailed and informative it failed to mention some key information in the assumption that everyone knows how to use `phpinfo()`

For those that don't:

Navigate to your webservers root folder such as `/var/www/`

Within this folder create a text file called `info.php`

Edit the file and type `phpinfo()`

Navigate to the file such as: `http://www.example.com/info.php`

Here you will see the `php.ini` path under `Loaded Configuration File`:

[image: phpinfo]

Make sure you delete `info.php` when you are done.

Comment: Also note that this is a potential security risk. The information printed is best kept not being publicly visible. Either keep it up for a very small amount of time and don't forget to either remove the file or change it's read permissions afterwards; or, better, restrict access to it straight away. Either deny access to that page via your web server configuration files or even just wholesale restrict http access via iptables temporarily.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on the situation, for me its in fpm as I'm using PHP5-FPM. A solution to your problem could be a universal php.ini and then using a symbolic link created like:

```
ln -s /etc/php5/php.ini php.ini
```

Then any modifications you make will be in one general .ini file.
This is probably not really the best solution though, you might want to look into modifying some configuration so that you literally use one file, on one location. Not multiple locations hacked together.

Comment: I don't understand the link. php5/php.ini does not exist, should I create it?

Comment: @HappyDeveloper uh sorry it might be simply /etc/php/

Comment: Anyway I can't set some options like display_erros = On, I suspect suhosin is making sure to turn that off after all the php.ini's are loaded.

Comment: dump your settings with phpinfo() and try modifying your settings through code. Check where it is loading your settings from.

Comment: Additional .ini files parsed  /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/suhosin.ini

Comment: @Toskan depends on where you want to have the universal php.ini file, I'd say wherever your php is installed but it just depends on what you personally need.

Answer (score 3):

You can find what is the php.ini file used:

- By add **phpinfo()** in a php page and display the page (like the picture under)
- From the shell, enter: php -i

Next, you can find the information in the Loaded Configuration file (so here it's /user/local/etc/php/php.ini)

Sometimes, you have indicated (none), in this case you just have to put your custom php.ini that you can find here: http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=php.ini-production;hb=HEAD

[image]

I hope this answer will help.

Comment: Thank you! In the shell this helped me finding the line `php -i | grep Conf`.