# Image transfer only working with certain permissions?

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions, ubuntu-14.04

I am using PHP to move an image to a specific directory. It fails if I have /tmp/ with permissions 755 but it doesn't fail if I have it with 777. Since 777 is not secure, is there any other method to do this?

My PHP code is this:

```
$dir = '/var/www/spectrom.benrosen.org/uploadedimages/';
$file = basename($_FILES['uploadimage']['name']);
$uploadfile = $dir . randomize() . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
 exit('{"result": "successful"}');
} else {
         exit('{"result": "could not upload image."}');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about the /tmp folder. Any user should be able to write to it. You shouldn't leave anything sensitive in the tmp folder.

This will also fail depending on the settings of your uploadimages folder. Make the owner of that folder the PHP process. That is system dependent. If running apache it may be controllable through .htaccess but definitely httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

Garr is right about the /tmp folder. Any way, if you are worried about the folder security please check this http://shapeshed.com/securing_upload_folders_in_php_on_unix_servers/ it explains how to convert the upload folder permission to 755.

Comment: What user would I want to give it permission for, running PHP?

Comment: Read that page completely, it describes change the owner of the upload folder to the running Apache and PHP , Usually "www", "apache" or "nobody." Also it specifies if you didn’t know it, ask your hosting company. We used "www" as the owner name

Comment: I use nginx, and I host my own server.

Comment: Ok, in general depends on many things like how you configured your server. But, best stone to pick is the php.ini user and group, use that as the owner name. As you are saying that, you are using nginx, be carefull with the php.ini files. Go thru this it helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665783/php-ini-which-one