# How to Increase max file upload in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have a small problem with upload file.
I was set in php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

But when I re-check, it still have old value

```
upload_max_filesize 2M
```

[value in phpinfo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQtYm.png)

I used php7-fpm with nginx, and restarted after change php.ini.
Please help me, thanks.

Comment: You're probably running a custom per-user php-ini. Check which ini file was loaded with phpinfo();

Comment: @Sander Backus: can you explain more detail for me? 
Because I edit the file was show in phpinfo();

Loaded Configuration File /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini

Comment: In phpinfo() check the variable "Loaded Configuration File" and make sure you editing these variables in the same file.

Comment: @kevin Run `php --ini` in terminal and share.... loaded configuration file value

Comment: @kevin please restart xampp or wamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do Changes in you config file `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini` and save it.

Then run the following commands:

```
sudo service php7-fpm restart
sudo service nginx restart
```

Check phpinfo() it will work!

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I miss restart php7-fpm.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably editing php.ini fole for PHP command-line.

This topic discuss php.ini location for nginx (also fpm is mentioned here):
[php.ini: which one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665783/php-ini-which-one)

Comment: I edited php.ini for php-fpm, that was located in:  /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini