# PHP Allowed memory size exhausted in Laravel/Intervention

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, upload, intervention

I have a web page that upload an image to my API Laravel Project.
It work until I upload image of size great or equals to **2mb** it run in an nginx 500 error:

```
2018/02/24 15:57:50 [error] 3420#3420: *19 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/project-folder/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Gd/Decoder.php on line 136
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 73728 bytes) in /var/www/project-folder/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444" while reading response header from upstream, client: *IP*, server: api.website.com, request: "POST /api/v1/posts HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "api.website.com"
```

I read of a ton of same questions in stack overflow and in google, but nothing seems to work.

Reading the error message carefully I can understand that from my PHP configuration the website can take **134217728 bytes** memory but it fail trying allocate **73728 bytes**: does it has any sense? 
It fails on only 0.7mb memory of max 128mb allowed!

Another stranger thing is that from my loaded php.ini file (running `php -i | grep 'php.ini'` I get message `Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`) I can read the values:

1. `memory_limit => 256M => 256M`
2. `post_max_size => 16M => 16M`
3. `upload_max_filesize => 16M => 16M`

I already tried to restart php-fm, restart server, put `ini_set('memory_limit','256M');` before Intervention code inside my php class but nothing happens.

Why is this happening?
Why 128MB/0.7MB if I have 256M/16MB inside my php configuration?

Thanks

Comment: The PHP binary used by the command line is (probably) different than the one being used by Nginx. Make sure have the right settings in Nginx as well (the settings in your answer are for the CLI version)

Comment: The message means that it has already allocated 128MB so it failed to allocate an additional 0.7 MB. That means your 256MB limit is not in effect

Answer (score 0):

you should edit this file

```
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
```

and try to allocate memory from that ini file

**An excerpt from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10665920/2693543)**

> Generally speaking, the `cli/php.ini` file is used when the PHP binary
>   is called from the command-line.  You can check that running php --ini
>   from the command-line.
>
> `fpm/php.ini` will be used when PHP is run as FPM -- which is the case
>   with an nginx installation.  And you can check that calling `phpinfo()`
>   from a php page served by your webserver.