# PHP.ini memory_limit not updating

Tags: php, laravel-valet

I have installed PHP through Homebrew and I'm using Laravel Valet to serve my projects locally. I would like to update the `memory_limit` in PHP.ini but for some reason it looks like it's not updating.

If I run `php --ini` I get:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.4
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini
```

I've updated `memory_limit` in both `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini` and `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini`.

Then I run:

```
brew services restart php@7.4
```

and

```
valet restart
```

If I then display `phpinfo()` in my project it still says `memory_limit = 128M`.

Comment: Does `ini_set('memory_limit','200M');` at the start of `index.php` file work ok?

Comment: You are likely not making a distinction between CLI and PHP-FPM configurations of PHP, as they are separate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php.ini: which one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665783/php-ini-which-one)

Comment: @NicoHaase no because `phpinfo()` displays the same loaded config files.

Comment: Have you checked whether there is any other code setting that limit, like a `ini_set` call or a `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this problem on mac:

I run: `php --ini`
It output:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.4
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/error_log.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini
```

I edited `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini`
Restart php.
Still same issue.

Then I edited `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini`,
restart.
It worked.